# Is there a way to open files from Transmit in Sublime Text 2 as new tab, not new window?

Tags: ftp, sublimetext

I use Transmit as FTP-client and Sublime Text 2 as text editor. When I open file from Transmit to edit it in Sublime Text 2 it opens in new window. It's pretty awkward. Is there a way to open files from Transmit in Sublime Text 2 as new tab of same editor window, not as new window at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following line to your Preferences → User Settings:

```
"open_files_in_new_window": false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open_files_in_new_window global setting for the former, and take a look through the File/Switch File menu for the latter